# Compaq Mini netbook, wireless problem

Tags: 10.10, wireless

I have a Compaq Mini and I had just installed Ubuntu 10.10 in it and everything runs great.

Except for the fact that it can only connect to the internet by ethernet connection and not wireless.

I had installed Ubuntu 10.10 replacing Windows 7 Enterprise (don't ask why I did that) and it doesn't seem to detect any wireless networks nearby.

Comment: What model? what wifi card? have you installed any drivers for it? need more details than that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the option to upgrade your Ubuntu to v.11.04 and your wireless will be fixed automatically !! I fixed a laptop and a desktop using this solution !!! They say it's a bug !!!

Comment: thnx :P that pretty much did it,and then there was some drivers tht were installed automatically so im good :P thnx everyone :)